# How to traverse a website with bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a small script to traverse the quotedb website to get the quote of day , i am using bs4

How do i traverse the content returned to find the quote of the day?

The thing is i am finding it pretty hard to traverse or even understand the content of the website. Where do i begin or how do i do so?

Comment: Check out the docs for Beautiful Soup to learn how to traverse HTML documents. Then view the source of quotedb.com and figure out what steps you'll need to take to extract the content you want.

Comment: If the quote is contained within an element that's unique on the page, you could just grab that element with bs.  Otherwise you'll have to drill down through the structure of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

get_page = requests.get("https://www.quotedb.com/")
soupify = BeautifulSoup(get_page.text, 'html.parser')
quote = soupify.find('a', href=re.compile('//www.quotedb.com/quote'))
print(quote.text)
```

Output:

```
"The President of the United States hears a hundred voices telling him that he is the greatest man in the world. He must listen carefully to hear the one voice that tells him he's not."
```